# How to restore optimizer by tf.train.Checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to restore the optimizer's state, so I did the following:

```
# create optimizer
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1)

# save
ckpt_dir = 'logs\\ckpts\\ckpt_0'
optm_ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer)
optm_ckpt.save(os.path.join(ckpt_dir, 'adam', 'adam_ckpt'))

# restore and check
optm_ckpt.restore(os.path.join(root_dir, ckpt_dir, 'adam_ckpt'))
print(optimizer.get_config()['learning_rate'])
```

However, I got the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for logs/ckpts/ckpt_0/adam_ckpt
```

Also I notice that the file size is just *1kb*... Could some one offer some opinion? Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics) link may help you to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

while creating checkpoints you can pass the optimizer argument for saving the optimizer status

```
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, model=model)
```

Then you can restore optimizer status while restoring those checkpoints.For more details please [refer](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#train_and_checkpoint_the_model) to this documentation. Thank You.